# Find the biggest change in values in a list?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

How would you find the biggest difference/change in values of a list of numbers in Excel?

An example of what I'm looking for is `1,3,4,5,9,10,11,13`

The value I would look for is `4` as this is the biggest difference (between `5` and `9`).

Is there a way to do this with a list in Excel?

Comment: this question is not a good fit for stackoverflow as it's not about programming. Try [SuperUser](http://superuser.com)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A picture is worth a thousand words? :p

[image]

**EDIT**:

Description added:

As shown in the image, put the formula in `=A2-A1` in Cell B2 and then drag it down. Once you have your values, use the `Max` formula to get the maximum value as shown in Cell `D5`

Comment: the `:p` is unnecessary in your answer ;) there are only 30 characters required ;) but this question could be answered only with the picture haha

Comment: The simple ways are always the best. Stupid me :S

Comment: @BGeaney:; `The simple ways are always the best.` You couldn't have put that better :)

Answer (score 2):

Add another column to contain the difference. Assuming your values are in column A, then the formula would be "=A2-A1" copied down the list. Few ways after this.

(1) You can eyeball which is largest

(2) you can copy values (make sure is values) to a this column and sort descending

(3) You can build pivot off that this column. and double click the largest to find the detail

Comment: + 1 Good suggestions :)

Answer (score 2):

If values are in distinct cells (A1:A8):

```
=MAX($A$2:$A$8-$A$1:$A$7)
```

seems to work (as an array formula, enter with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>).

Answer (score 1):

1. Put the values in a column.Say, Column A
2. In cell B1; write a formula. =A2-A1
3. Copy the same formula to the entire Column B, for every value in column A
4. Go to the end of column B, and write a new formula, =MAX (B1:B)
   [image]

Comment: Remember not to drag the formula all the way down. This will fail if the max value in difference is less than the value of the last element.

Answer (score 1):

Create a new column with the differences:

```
=A2-A1
```

And drag down.

Find the max value:

```
=MAX(B1:B9)
```

Find the index of the max difference value:

```
=MATCH(MAX(B1:B9);B1:B9;0)
```